# how to change Maven default project output directory？

Tags: java, maven

**Hello everyone：**

I need help , I'm new to maven. when I try to run my first maven command

in **Windows 7** like:

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DgroupId=com.helloworld.test \
    -DpackageName=com.helloworld.test \
    -Dpackage=com.helloworld.test \
    -DartifactId=hello
```

and it succeed, and here is an output:

```
[INFO] project created from Archetype in dir: C:\Windows\system32\helloworld
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

my question is: how to change the default output directory ? like:

```
d:\maven\project\helloworld
```

thank you very much.

Comment: `cd D:\maven\project` ?

Answer (score 1):

Either execute command from target directory or pass `-Dbasedir=/path/to/dir`

Comment: thank you. but could you give the exactly answer with example to me, I really a new hand. and [-Dbasedir=/path/to/dir] will not work in windows as I have tried in cmd path : c:\windows\system32 . but [cd D:\maven\project] is worked.

Comment: try `-Dbasedir=C:\\windows\\system32`, I wonder why you want to create project in that directory though