# How to change globally maven default target directory?

Tags: java, maven, settings, pom.xml, target

I've guessed about changing my output target directory for maven builds.
More people as i've seen asked the [approximately same question](https://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/200512.mbox/%3Cc7c567b10512140827n7b6d91f2i@mail.gmail.com%3E), which i rephrased a bit:

> I would like that all the generated files for all my m2 projects go to
>   specific, different than default, build directory. For example, if I
>   have projects P1 and P2, the default build directories are P1/target
>   and P2/target. I'd like to change it to something like P1/target
>   and P2/target/ **or even better - temp/P1/target
>   and /temp/P2/target**.
>
> I don't want to modify every single pom.xml. I'd like to have this as
>   a global, my environment specific setting.
>
> It looks like several of maven plugins base their build directory path
>   on "project.build.directory" so I tried sth like "m2 -
>   Dproject.build.directory=/temp/target package" but this has no effect.
>
> Is anyone aware any working way to achieve this - either through
>   settings.xml or through -D or some other global approach?

Comment: i've found solution for -D option, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22741072/how-to-change-maven-default-project-output-directory

yet global setting seems much better for me.

Comment: Maven advocates "convention over configuration". The convention says it's gonna be `target/`, relative to the `pom.xml`. You can fight that, but you're just going to hit your head into a wall, more than once. Also, new people will join your project (that are familiar with Maven) and they're gonna be confused of this out-of-the-ordinary project. Ask yourself (or tell us) what it really is that you're trying to achieve, rather than your (what seems like) your taste telling you things should go into a different directory than what's default?

Comment: The goal is very, very simple. Compile output grabs valuable space, and i don't need it all those classes after development is done. If u have many projects in ur dev folders, just look what space is in /target folders...
Yes, i can clean it. But i'm lazy...

Other devs wont see my config policy for target, unless i do it in my pom.xml.
i hope my goal is quite clear now.

Comment: So i want to change the convention via local configuration in a way not disturbing other possible users of projects and expect comments to the point.

Comment: Would you not be better off with symlinks then?

Comment: Could you provide an example, how it could be done without changing pom.xml?

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of symlinking `./target` to `/temp/P2/target`, but then later I realized that a `mvn clean` would try to wipe out the symlink too. Never mind.

Answer (score 0):

If you found the `-D` solution then it is easy to make it global.
Just use the `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable. Maven will pick this up and will apply it to every build.

On Windows (or set it using the UI)

```
set MAVEN_OPTS=-DsomeSystemProp=value
```

or on Linux

```
export MAVEN_OPTS=-DsomeSystemProp=value
```

Source: https://maven.apache.org/configure.html

**Note 1:** The `.mvn` directory in your `.m2` directory is also an option but I never used this on user level.

**Note 2:** The thing with convention over configuration that people tend to forget the configuration part. I have seen hard coded `target` directories as output directories in plugins and `pom.xml` files. Be aware of this and if something behaves funny try the build with the standard output directory.

Answer (score 0):

In an old project we used ramdisk to speed up the build.

I had to set the `M2_RAMDISK` environment variable to my ramdisk the rest was taken care of.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>poc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ramdisk</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <build>
        <directory>${override.project.build.directory}</directory>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <override.project.build.directory>target</override.project.build.directory>
    </properties>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>ramdisk</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>env.M2_RAMDISK</name>
                </property>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <override.project.build.directory>${env.M2_RAMDISK}/${project.groupId}/${project.artifactId}/${project.version}</override.project.build.directory>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

Overriding the build's output directory is risky business as some tool just use the `target` directory instead of the property value.